# in android multi modular app using PagingSourceFactory how to convert entity to domain , using MediatorResult?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, pagination, dao

I'm stuck in a problem using the latest library of Paginator3 in an Android multimodular application.

My app modules:

- app
- data
- domain
- usecases

In domain module I've got the class: CharacterDomain --> used in all modules.

In app module I've got the class CharacterEntity which is used in DAOs

then also in app module I use a MVVM Architecture:

**Invoke to fetch data in VM:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getCharactersUseCase: GetCharactersUseCase) : ViewModel(){

    private val TAG = "HomeViewModel"

    fun getCharacters(): Flow<PagingData<CharacterDomain>> = getCharactersUseCase.invoke().cachedIn(viewModelScope)

}
```

**Collect data in fragment:**

```
    private fun startSearchJob() {
        searchJob?.cancel()
        searchJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
            homeFragmentViewModel.getCharacters()
                .collectLatest {
                    charactersAdapter.submitData(it)
                }
        }
    }
```

**charactersAdapter --> Adapter of type:**  PagingDataAdapter<CharacterDomain, CharactersAdapter.CharacterViewHolder>(DiffUtilCallBack())

**in usecases module:**

```
class GetCharactersUseCase(private val characterRepository: CharacterRepository) {

    operator fun invoke(): Flow<PagingData<CharacterDomain>> = characterRepository.getCharacters()

}
```

**in data module:**

```
//TODO implement Local Data methods

class CharacterRepository( /*private val localCharactersDataSource: LocalCharactersDataSource,*/
                          private val remoteCharactersDataSource: RemoteCharactersDataSource){

    fun getCharacters(): Flow<PagingData<CharacterDomain>> = remoteCharactersDataSource.getAllCharacters()

}
```

**in app module:**

**HERE I GOT MY ERROR**
in:
pagingSourceFactory = {
zaradatabase.getCharacterDao().getCharacters()

I need to convert this character types from entities to domain, but I cannot mapping

```
class CharacterRemoteServerImpl(private val characterRemoteServer: CharacterRemoteServer,
                                private val zaradatabase: ZaraDatabase
) : RemoteCharactersDataSource {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
    override fun getAllCharacters(): Flow<PagingData<CharacterDomain>> =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE,
                prefetchDistance = 10,
                enablePlaceholders = false,
                initialLoadSize = 2
            ),
                pagingSourceFactory = {
                zaradatabase.getCharacterDao().getCharacters()
            },
            remoteMediator = CharactersMediator(characterRemoteServer,
                zaradatabase)
        ).flow
    
}
```

My Dao:

```
@Dao
interface CharacterDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAll(characters: List<CharacterEntity>)

    @Query("SELECT * From characters ORDER BY page")
    fun getCharacters(): PagingSource<Int, CharacterEntity>

    @Query("DELETE FROM characters")
    suspend fun clearAllCharacters()


}
```

and finally my remoteMediator:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
class CharactersMediator(
private val characterRemoteServer: CharacterRemoteServer,
private val zaraDatabase: ZaraDatabase): RemoteMediator\<Int, CharacterDomain\>() {

    //region Override Methods
    
    override suspend fun initialize(): InitializeAction {
        val timeout = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    
        return if (System.currentTimeMillis() - (zaraDatabase.getRemoteKeysDao().getCreationTime() ?: 0) < timeout) {
            InitializeAction.SKIP_INITIAL_REFRESH   //Cache up to date
        } else {
            InitializeAction.LAUNCH_INITIAL_REFRESH //Need to refresh
        }
    }
    
    override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, CharacterDomain>
    ): MediatorResult {
    
        val page = when (loadType) {
    
            LoadType.REFRESH -> {
                val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeyClosestToAnchorPosition(state)
                remoteKeys?.nextKey?.minus(1) ?: 1
            }
    
            LoadType.PREPEND -> {
                val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeyForFirstCharacter(state)
                val prevKey = remoteKeys?.prevKey
                prevKey ?: return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = remoteKeys != null)
            }
    
            LoadType.APPEND -> {
                val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeyForLastCharacter(state)
                val nextKey = remoteKeys?.nextKey
                nextKey ?: return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = remoteKeys != null)
            }
        }
    
        try {
            val networkResponse = characterRemoteServer.getCharacters(page)
    
            delay(1000L) //TODO For testing only! check endOfPaginationReached
    
            val characters = networkResponse.results
            val networkResponseInfo = networkResponse.info
            val endOfPaginationReached = networkResponse.info.next == null
    
            zaraDatabase.withTransaction {
                if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                    zaraDatabase.getRemoteKeysDao().clearRemoteKeys()
                    zaraDatabase.getCharacterDao().clearAllCharacters()
                }
    
                val prevKey = if (page > 1) page - 1 else null
                val nextKey = if (endOfPaginationReached) null else page + 1
                val remoteKeys = characters.map { character ->
                    RemoteKeys( character.id, prevKey, page, nextKey)
                }
    
                val charactersMapped = characters.map {
                    it.toCharacterEntity(page)
                }
    
                zaraDatabase.getRemoteKeysDao().insertAll(remoteKeys)
                zaraDatabase.getCharacterDao().insertAll(charactersMapped.onEachIndexed { _, _ -> })
            }
            return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = endOfPaginationReached)
        } catch (error: IOException) {
            return MediatorResult.Error(error)
        } catch (error: HttpException) {
            return MediatorResult.Error(error)
        }
    }
    
    //endregion Override Methods
    
    //region Private Methods
    
    private suspend fun getRemoteKeyForLastCharacter(state: PagingState<Int, CharacterDomain>): RemoteKeys? {
        return state.pages.lastOrNull {
            it.data.isNotEmpty()
        }?.data?.lastOrNull()?.let { character ->
            zaraDatabase.getRemoteKeysDao().getRemoteKeyByCharacterID(character.id)
        }
    }
    
    private suspend fun getRemoteKeyForFirstCharacter(state: PagingState<Int, CharacterDomain>): RemoteKeys? {
        return state.pages.firstOrNull {
            it.data.isNotEmpty()
        }?.data?.firstOrNull()?.let { character ->
            zaraDatabase.getRemoteKeysDao().getRemoteKeyByCharacterID(character.id)
        }
    }
    
    private suspend fun getRemoteKeyClosestToAnchorPosition(state: PagingState<Int, CharacterDomain>): RemoteKeys? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { position ->
            state.closestItemToPosition(position)?.id?.let { id ->
                zaraDatabase.getRemoteKeysDao().getRemoteKeyByCharacterID(id)
            }
        }
    }
    
    //endregion Private Methods

}
```

I tried mapping the type of data without violating the rules of modules